# How to apply css just to element that curser is on?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd appreciate if you could help me with my problem. I'm trying to apply css just to one element, that my mouse is over.

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ShareImage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ShareCode</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

That's how the menu looks like. And I want to turn the background of li element brighter when you put cursor over it.

I tried something like this

```
$(function(){
  $('header a').hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function(){
      $('header ul li').css("background-color", "#3A3A3A");
    });
  });
})
```

But it doesn't work how I want it to work, I haven't used jQuery for a while and now I forgot everything. Thanks everybody for helping me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
}
```

No need for jQuery.

**EDIT:**

For the fading effect requested in the comments, this is the simplest CSS (fading of 1 second in this example):

```
header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As experienced, defining the transition property for `li:hover` breaks the fade in/out effect. You need to define it for the element without the pseudoclass. So, our final CSS code would be:

```
header ul li {
    transition: 1s;
}

header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it's the solution but I want to make it animated kind of, I want that fade in effect.

Comment: @lucas: This acts on hover of the list item, rather than on the anchor, but that may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @Danny this is also possible in CSS3. I will update the answer.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti, interesting answer. I never used transition in css. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @lucasnadalutti is there any way to fadeOut effect too? Because when I put the cursor over it, it has nice fadeIn effect, but when I put the mouse away it just get to it's original background color.

Comment: @Danny this wasn't supposed to happen. Try to increase the fade time to see if you just wasn't noticing the fade out effect. I made this simple fiddle so you can see that the fade out effect also happens: https://jsfiddle.net/5gdv9vg6/

Comment: @lucasnadalutti that's strange, it works correctly on jsfiddle but incorrectly at my page lol

Comment: Just got what's going on. You need to define the transition in your element without the :hover pseudo class, just like it's in the fiddle. Otherwise, you'll experience this odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
$('header a').hover(function(){
  $('header ul li').css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function(){
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#3A3A3A");
    });  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ShareImage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ShareCode</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```